# Python Pass Object between classes

Tags: python, pexpect

Hi I would like to know how do I pass obeject between classes. I'm going to use my script to first login to our server, next to client server and than to the routers and switches.
Here is the script:
the file name is connect.py:

```
    import expect
 
class domain_connect:

        def __init__(self,usr='user',pwd='password',d1='192.168.1.3',dclient='192.168.2.3'):
        self._usr =us
        self._pwd =pwd
        self._d1 =d1
        self._dclient =dclient
 
    def djump(self):
            
        child=pexpect.spawn('ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ' +self._usr+" "+self._d1) 
        child.expect('assword:')
        child.sendline(self._pwd)
        child.expect(':~>')
        ##Connect to client server
        child.sendline(self._dclient)
        child.expect('assword:')
        child.sendline(self._pwd)
        child.expect('accept:')
        child.sendline(' ')
        child.expect(':~>')
        return child
 
class ce_connect:
    def __init__(self, child, ip, usr, pwd, enpwd):
        self._child = child
        self._ip = ip
        self._usr = usr
        self._pwd = pwd
        self._enpwd = pwd
 
    def cjump(self):
        ##Connecting to router
        child.sendline('ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l '+self._usr+' '+self._ip)
        return self._child
```

Here is the script that use:

```
import connect

child = connect.domain_connect()
child = child.djump() ## At this point I'm good toward the client server
```

I was trying to do the following to pass the child object to the ce_connect class

```
    child2 = connect.ce_connect(child, '192.78.1.20', 'username', 'password', 'password2')
    child2 = child2.cjump()
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'spawn' object has no attribute 'djump'
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation. I think I can guess what's supposed to be under what, but I could be wrong, which might make my answer wrong. (And it deters other people from even trying to answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already *are* successfully passing the `child` object to the `ce_connect` constructor.

When you do this:

```
child2 = connect.ce_connect(child, '192.78.1.20', 'username', 'password', 'password2')
```

… that passes `child` to the `ce_connect` constructor, so `child2._child` ends up being the same object as `child`. So, when you call `child2.cjump()`, and that calls `self._child.dump()`, it's calling `djump` on your `child` object. Just as it should.

The problem is that `child` isn't a `domain_connect` object, it's a `pexpect.spawn` object. That's why you get that `AttributeError: 'spawn' object has no attribute 'djump'`, which means exactly what it says.

The reason for that is simple:

```
child = child.djump()
```

This sets `child` to whatever `djump` returns. What `djump` returns is a `pexpect.spawn` object. Before that line, `child` was a `domain_connect`, but now, it's a `spawn`, and you no longer have any accessible reference to the `domain_connect`.

The answer is simple: don't do that. Keep a reference to the `domain_connect`, and use it. Something like this:

```
child = connect.domain_connect()
child_jump = child.djump()
child2 = connect.ce_connect(child, '192.78.1.20', 'username', 'password', 'password2')
child2_jump = child2.cjump()
```

As a side note, I think reusing the name `child` inside the method implementation and in the calling code is confusing you. It's easier to keep things straight if you can come up with distinct names.

---

Meanwhile, once you fix this, you have another problem. Your code seems to expect the `child` of a `ce_connect` to be both a `domain_connect` *and* a `pexpect.spawn` at the same time. In particular, inside `ce_connect.cjump`, you've got this:

```
child.sendline('ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l '+self._usr+' '+self._ip)
```

There's no `sendline` method of a `domain_connect` object.

It's hard to decide what the right fix is here. You need to get straight in your head what each of these objects is supposed to be. Why are they all called `child`? What is a child supposed to mean?

One possibility is that the `child` objects are supposed to be the `pexpect` child processes, not the `*_connect` objects, so what you really want is something like this:

```
domain = connect.domain_connect()
child = domain.djump()
ce = connect.ce_connect(child, '192.78.1.20', 'username', 'password', 'password2')
child2 = ce.cjump()
```

Or, maybe you actually have no use for these `connect` objects at all, just the results of their `djump`/`cjump` methods. In which case you could write it as:

```
child = connect.domain_connect().djump()
child2 = connect.ce_connect(child, '192.78.1.20', 'username', 'password', 'password2').cjump()
```

But in that case, you'd probably be better off making the public interface be a pair of module-level functions, and hide the classes under the implementation of those functions.

Or, maybe you want to let the `domain_connect` objects act as child processes on top of whatever else they represent, by holding onto the result of `djump` as a `_child` member, then delegating `sendline`, and maybe other methods, to the real `pexpect` object, like this:

```
def sendline(self, line):
    return self._child.sendline(line)
```

Or… well, as I said, there are many possibilities, and without knowing how your design is supposed to work and what your classes and variables are supposed to represent, there's really no way to say how to make your code fit your design.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "connect.py", line 38, in cjump
    self._child.sendline('ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l '+self._usr+' '+self._ip)
AttributeError: domain_connect instance has no attribute 'sendline'

Comment: That's because of another bug in your code. I'll edit the answer to try to explain.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. I'm new with python, just couple of months of programming. I'm a network engineer and thanks for guys like you that help others, my job is a lot easy because I can automate most of the most intense tasks.